# Add previous state to the current state(list) in NgRX

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

I've been trying to resolve this part.

```
export const personReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,

    on(LOAD_ALL_SUCCESS, (state, { list }) => {
        // list.push(state.entities)
        const tmpArr : Person[] = Object.values(state.entities)
        
        tmpArr.forEach(t =>{
            list.push(t)
        })

        return adapter.addAll(list, {
            ...state,
            loaded: true,
            loading: false,
            saved201: false,
            updated200: false,
            error: undefined,
            formState: undefined,
        })
    }),
)
```

My Goal here is to add the previous state to my current state so that my list of person contains the previous and the current which i will display in my ui.
Which means i have to display all even if i move to the next page.

I thought i could convert the `state.entities` from dictionary to array but it's giving me an error. Is there a way to do achieve my goal?

Btw. in my UI i'm not using the typical pagination but rather scroll down (which display or pull data if the scroll reach the bottom like in facebook news feed)

I'm using ngrx v10
https://ngrx.io/

```
    "@ngrx/effects": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^10.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^10.0.0",
    "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators": "^2.0.0",
```

for the selector

```
export const selectAll = createSelector(
    selectorPersonFeature,
    adapter.getSelectors().selectAll
)
```

So I ended up with this.

```
this.store.pipe(select(selectAll))
      .subscribe((p: Person[]) => {
        p.forEach(i => {
          this.person$.push(i)
        })
      })
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

there are some other methods you can use...
try to use `adapter.addMany()`
https://ngrx.io/api/data/EntityCollectionReducerMethods#addMany